# VSCode Debugger Just sits there and does nothing

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

So I have an Angular project and really want to get the debugging working with VSCode and Chrome. I have already read about 30 different guides and tutorials on configs and different debug recipes and tried them all. I checked everywhere here on stack overflow and a lot of the posts seem to be deprecated and offer no solution. I want to get the `launch` config working (not the attach). Here is my current launch.json:

```
  {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Angular Launch",
          "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "./*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "*": "*",
            "./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Whenever I press run debug, it just loads forever like so and nothing ever happens:
[image: What happens after clicking run debug]

I have tried changing around the different parameters, I have enabled remote debugging in Chrome, used `userDir` to true and false. I've gotten it to launch a couple times, with no change to the config which launches chrome, then the debug toolbar disappears with no logs, warnings, or errors. I have tried disabling all extensions except for the Chrome Debugger plugin.

Current versions:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.7
@angular/cli                      6.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3
@schematics/angular               0.6.7
@schematics/update                0.6.7
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

VSCode: Latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Angular Launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "https://localhost:4200/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
  ]
}
```

Apparently this was the perfect answer somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `.vscode/` folder is in your root folder. Then make sure you have the `Debugger for Chrome` installed. 
Refactor your `launch.json` using this config:

```
{
 "name": "Angular Launch",
 "type": "chrome",
 "request": "launch",
 "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"   // <- make sure here you have not subfolder.
}
```

then start your angular app using `ng serve` or npm scripts like `npm run start`. Navigate to the debugger menu and run your launch.

Comment: Ya that doesnt work still, it just hangs there and has a loading bar and I can't stop the debugger when I press stop nothing happens.